# Windows 10 only boots after pressing the reset button

Tags: windows-10, boot

My PC is self-built and has the following components:

- Intel i5 6600K
- Arctic Freezer 33 E-Sports Cooler
- MSI Z170-A
- Radeon Sapphire Nitro RX480 8GB
- Kingston 8GB DDR4 3000 MHZ RAM
- Crucial SSD MX300 120 GB
- WD Blue 500 GB
- Toshiba P300 2TB

Since a few weeks, Windows 10 only boots when I reset the PC, after it was turned off. Restarting is fine. But when the computer was shut down, only a reset will make it boot. It shows the Windows logo, then nothing happens. The dots circling will not appear.

The Windows event log does show the reset as kernel power event, but beyond that, no information is being logged:

[image: screenshot of kernel power event 41]

My SSD has 87% of life left, according to the Crucial software:

[image: screenshot of crucial smart status]

I ran `sfc /scannow` 2x on an elevated PowerShell and it found a few files that were repaired (probably from the resets), but this didn't solve the issue. A following "turn it off and on again" showed the same symptom.

The only thing I changed recently, was to disable Hyper-V as a Windows feature. However, the Hyper-V switch is still present. The other thing I noticed, is that my wallpaper on the login screen is often gone and only a grey screen is shown instead. Not sure if that has anything to do with.

Comment: I am really not stupid when it comes to IT, but I am really at a loss here guys :D. Any help is appreciated. Fyi, I used Hyper-V for doing some work on Linux and disabled it when I was done.

Comment: What do you mean by "disable Hyper-V as a Windows feature. However, the Hyper-V switch is still present" ?

Comment: Does Windows boot in safe mode at first attempt? you can try clean boot https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135.

Comment: Restore point or backup to go back to?

Comment: @harrymc I disabled the Hyper-V Software in "Turn Windows features on or off". But the Hyper-V network adapter is still present in the network devices. As I said, not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Comment: @Hardoman No, the spinning wheel does not appear at all. No boot is possible into either mode. The only way is a hard reset. Then everything works fine, including gaming. Just played BF One at Ultra. So, enough power, Hardware works. It's weird.

Comment: There is no limit to the number of ways in which Windows 10 can self-destruct. The S.M.A.R.T. info is ok, but I would still run `chkdsk`. Check also the Event Viewer for errors. Several weeks after is problematic, so all I can suggest if you find nothing is [Repair Install Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was troubling me for a while, but after changing the power plan to "high performance", it went away. Seems like AMD cards have an issue with restoring their power state on other plans. What exactly caused it I still don't know, but I can shut down and boot now without having to reset.

Comment: Thanks for answering after finding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have desktop with robust graphics booster or similar, in BIOS, change to Fast or Turbo.

It works for me.